# Optical illusion of car wheels, speeding up

Tags: rotational-dynamics, everyday-life

Perhaps it is some free moving spinner attached to the wheel, but as opposed to this question: [Why does the wheel of a car appear to be moving in opposite direction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41006/why-does-the-wheel-of-a-car-appear-to-be-moving-in-opposite-direction)
I have seen car wheels that appear to spin backward both while speeding up, and moving at a constant rate. 
Am I just confused, or is there a reason for this?

Comment: This is more of a "psychophysics" question. If you would like to search for answers to this yourself, it's called the Wagon-wheel effect. See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagon-wheel_effect for example.

Comment: These effects are even more obvious with ceiling fans. In fact, if the frequency of the fan matched exactly with the frequency that we our eyes capture the images, then we should, in principle see the fan as stationary.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32263/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

Your eyes and brain process images at a fixed sampling rate.  This means that you only see the world in a series of quick images.  If those images are taken at such a rate that the images are taken in synch or multiples of your eye's sample rate the tire can appear to be still.  When that tire moves at a rate that is slightly lower than a multiple of your eye's rate it appears to move slightly backwards.  Likewise if it move slightly faster than a multiple of your eye's sample rate it appears to move slightly slower.  This effect is known as [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing).

Humans see about 10-12 frames per second (fps) (everyone's rate is a little different and different frames can be perceived at different rates).  If the tire spins at 1,000 frames per second our eye (if working at 10 fps) will only see 10 instances of that tire.  If they are in perfect synch it won't appear to have moved. Here's a [youtube example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-19SxqZ8Qs).

In 2004 a [newer theory](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0042698904002731) has been proposed called Temporal Aliasing.  Temporal aliasing is caused by the sampling rate (i.e. number of frames per second) of a scene being too low compared to the transformation speed of objects inside of the scene. This causes objects to appear to jump or appear at a location instead of giving the impression of smoothly moving towards them.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick There are two competing theories both unproven: sampling rate and temporal aliasing.  Both are based on sampling effects.  Your "continuous perception" that you experience is where the sampling problem occurs with certain rates of motion.

Comment: I think that this is entirely wrong - our eyes do not have a "framerate" in the same way that video cameras or monitors do.  Individual photoreceptors may have a maximum rate at which they can detect flickering, but since they are not synchronized in any meaningful way, this does not lead to a fixed "framerate". Also the brain has limits on how fast it can process individual images, but this is just a floor, not a framerate. You may see aliasing effects indoors when your light source is flickering at a fixed rate, but this has more to do with the light source than any "framerate" in our eyes.

Comment: @loneboat what do you think causes the aliasing?  It's not the light source.